# How to change dateformat in VB.NET 2010?

Tags: vb.net

I am using a `DateTimePicker` control in my form.

By selecting a date, it should be inserted in an *MS SQL* database. But, the date format in *VB* is (*DMY*) and is different from the format in *MS SQL* (*YMD*) !!

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Could you show some code? I suspect your handling your data as `String` where you should be using `DateTime` - namely not passing this value via SqlCommand Parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Use parametrised query to solve the problem. The following is an example:

```
Dim cmd as SqlCommand = new SqlCommand(
   "INSERT INTO table_name (username, logindate) 
    VALUES (@USERNAME, @DATE)", conn)

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@USERNAME", tbUserName.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DATE", dateTimePicker.Value)

int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

---

However, if you are interested in formatting your date value, the following articles may help you:

[Standard Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx#Y2000)

[Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Comment: Careful: Since the format should not be relevant when inserting data from a DateTimePicker into an SQL database (see Filburt's comment), this answer might solve Rachid's problem, but in a fundamentally wrong way.